# Convert byte array to picture

Tags: c++, qt

Hello I try to convert a byte array to an Image but each time i get a null image, somebody could help me please ?

```
QImage image("p.jpg");
qDebug()<<image;
  QImage image2;
QByteArray paquet2;
QDataStream out2(&paquet2, QIODevice::WriteOnly);

out2 << image;

qDebug()<<image2.fromData(paquet2,"jpg");
```

qDebug 1 result: QImage(Qsize(500,500))
qDebug 2 result: QImage(Qsize(0,0))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`fromData()` is a static method.

Try `image2.loadFromData(paquet2)` or `QImage::fromData(paquet2)` instead.

I noticed something very strange, this code works as expected:

```
  QImage img("...");
  QByteArray data;
  QBuffer buff(&data);
  QDataStream out(&buff);
  out << img;
  qDebug() << QImage::fromData(data);
```

But it gives a warning about the `IODevice` not being open.

If I manually `buff.open()`, `fromData()` produces a null image again.

Without explicitly opening, the `openMode()` is automatically set to `Unbuffered | WriteOnly` and it works, if I `open()` it explicitly to `Unbuffered | WriteOnly` it doesn't work. Go figure...